# Which eCommerce CMS will work in Tor?

Tags: javascript, development, performance, website

Which eCommerce CMS will work in Tor? I tried many CMS like OpenCart, Magento and Wordpress etc, but none of these open correctly in Tor browser, I mean only HTML markup loads up, but no images, stylesheets and scripts.

Also, can anyone advise me which CMS to choose? I want to build an eCommerce website for selling stuff. I'm on this issue for 3 weeks and haven't gotten any solution so far and I'm running out of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've done it, and thought by posting it would help others to not do mistake that I've done. Now i think any CMS can be run with Tor, I was installing CMS with normal Firefox Browser and than run on Tor browser that's where Path's Issue comes in.

So in simple words CMS/Framework will also need to be setup/install via Tor Browser.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with this and I can't advice on which system to use, but you should figure out **why** those systems won't load any linked files. Have you looked at the links? Are they correct? Are they absolute or relative URLs? Do you get 404s or other errors in your web server log?
There is probably some way to config where your document root is and where your linked assets should sit relative to that.

There is no reason why this would not work over the Tor network.

Comment: Here is the onion address you can check
6d3d76cpeycrl42j.onion

Comment: Yes i still think this way that there is no reason why it still can't run correctly, cause its running fine on normal browser like Firefox.

Comment: So first of all the site is on localhost (Xampp Server), and the paths are also absolute like (http://localhost/wp/...), but some absolute links which are coming from CDN like Google jQuery is loading fine. And yes if i go to another page than i got this error "Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost."

Comment: _"the paths are also absolute like (localhost/wp/...), "_ <-- this is why.

Comment: Sorry it was wordpess website in sub-directory in localhost thats why its showing paths like this. But I've also put Wordpess in root of localhost, so that gives same result mean images & scripts not loading in tor.

Comment: any suggestions for me?

Comment: anyone had a chance with any other ecommerce which supports bitcoins? I've tried LiteCart, its running fine in Tor but now its not supporting Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel can be a good option for this I found the best script that can be used as eCommerce for onion website

**https://tor.wittyanswer.com/onion-ecommerce-marketplace-script/**

this script is built especially for **TOR** network

**http://demo.botdigit.com/**

**Feature of this script and CMS ?**

1. Laravel Security Features
2. Reduce Laravel Vulnerabilities From CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery)
3. Protection against XSS (Cross-Site Scripting)
4. SQL Injection
5. Improve Laravel Application Security
6. Laravel Security Packages